# Assigning the output of cin to variables

Tags: c++, variables, user-input, getline, cin

I'm trying to learn how to use  `cin` and `getline` to write a paper grading program that I can use at school. It's kind of a tricky project for a beginner but it lets me know what I need to learn and this is the first thing I need to do.

```
int main()
{
    string grader;
    int x;
    cout << "Who will I be assisting today? ";
    getline (cin, grader);
    cout << "Hello " << grader << ".\n";
    cout << "How manny questions are on the test you will be grading? ";
    getline (cin, x);
    cout << "this is a " << x << "question test graded by" << grader << ".\n";
}
```

Lets say I answered John Doe for the first question, then 20 for question two. I want it to print "this is a 20 question test graded by John Doe"
Where am I going wrong? 
I'm sure it's a stupid mistake but it's bugging me. I'm a novice so sorry for the ignorance. I will have more questions regarding this program that will not have to do with user in-put. is it ok to post these questions here, or start new topics?
thanks

Comment: `getline (cin, x);` doesn't make sense and thus will result in an error because `x` is an `int`.

Comment: You probably want a simple `cin >> x;` or something like `getline(cin,tmp); x = std::stoi(tmp);`.

Comment: 1) `cin >> x;` for streaming a formatting `int` variable will probably do what you want. 2) you claimed you would, now do so. return a valid 'int' from `main()`, preferably `EXIT_SUCCESS` if all went well.

Comment: __"I will have more questions regarding this program that will not have to do with user in-put. is it ok to post these questions here, or start new topics?"__  post as new question, it makes it easier for others to find answers to their own questions if they have similar.

Comment: Oh, of course it doesn't make sense. I don't know why I wrote it that way. like i said, stupid mistake. i was in the swing of useing getline for strings with white spaces. cin<< x; took care of it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since you did not state what was your error, and alas it could also be a missing include/namespace.
The complete runnable/compilable program would be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string grader;
    int x;
    cout << "Who will I be assisting today? ";
    getline (cin, grader);
    cout << "Hello " << grader << ".\n";
    cout << "How manny questions are on the test you will be grading? ";
    cin >> x;
    cout << "this is a " << x << "question test graded by" << grader << ".\n";
}
```

anyway, this will immediatly close after you entered the amount of questions (or you call your exe from a shell/cmd) - so dont wonder if you cant see the result.

Comment: What will immediately close?  The program will terminate, but this won't prevent you from seeing the output.

Comment: @James Unless you are running this in some Windows compiler/IDE setups which close the console immediately after `main()` returns...

Comment: @us2012 But who runs programs in that context, unless they are under the debugger (and you've set a breakpoint at the exit points).  (And I'm tempted to say: who would use a debugger so broken that it looses program output when the program being debugged terminates?)