# Uninitialised local variable from class

Tags: c++

When I'm trying to access classes public variable (in this case trying to input text row) it shows that it's uninitialized. However, I declared it in class as a public variable. 
I know that's some dummy mistake, but can't find it :D

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

class stringlength {
private:
    int lengt;
public:
    char * row;

    int len()
    {
        for (int i = 0, lengt = 0; (*(row + i) != '\0'); i++, lengt++) {}
        return lengt;
    }
};
int main()
{
    stringlength test;

    cout << "Enter a string:";
    cin >> test.row;
    cout << "Length is: " << test.len();
    _getch();

}
```

This program is expected to give a length of the inputted row (like strlen function)
Error is:

Error   C4700   uninitialized local variable 'test' used

Thanks for help ;)

Comment: Not only do you need to initialise `row`, you also need to allocate some memory to store the string in. Have a look at the [list of good books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Naive question, why don't you use a `std::string` ? It's easier to use and harder to miss use. And it's have a `.size()`

Comment: As @molbdnilo say, you need to initialise `row` . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15319690/char-and-cin-in-c may help

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15131772/assigning-cin-to-variables

Comment: std::string is easy. Yep :D But the task is about using a pointers to find the length

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declaring the variable does not mean that it's initialized.

Initialize it in a constructor, or just `char * row = nullptr;` (if 0 is the intended initialization).

Same for all the variables that you have which have no constructors.

Edit: in this specific case you need to initialize to a new pointer `char * row = new char[...]`

Comment: But I'm inputting it through cin. It seems a bit strange to me.

Comment: Initialising it as array helped.
```
char * row = new row [4096]

```